# Android: How to wrap text by chars? (Not by words)

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

For instance:

```
This is foo text for wrapping text in TextView
```

The way that TextView wraps is:

```
This is foo text for
wrapping text in ...
```

I want this:

```
This is foo text for wr
apping text in TextView
```

Comment: Hi christian, Im looking for the exact solution, But im unable to implement using your accepted answer. pls let me know how to get this done in a textview

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but you could replace spaces with the unicode no-break space character (U+00A0). This will cause your text to be treated as a single string and wrap on characters instead of words.

`myString.replace(" ", "\u00A0");`

Comment: I wouldn't call it so much of a hack. Isn't this exactly what the character is for?

Works like a charm.

Comment: Fair enough. I call it a hacky solution because this functionality should really be built into TextView. The iOS equivalent, UILabel, allows you to set the line break mode and has all sorts of wrapping and truncating modes.

Comment: This only takes care of unwanted linebreaks caused by spaces. The answer below from atarasenko is the real problem solver, since it also takes care of unwanted line breaks due to hyphens, semicolons etc.

Comment: A word of caution: If you need to use the string later, you may need to reverse the "replace". [This answer helped improve a "results" display within my app, but database lookups using getListAdapter().getItem(row).toString().substring(0, 20).trim() started failing until I realized that reversal was required]

Answer (score 7):

As I know, there is no such property for TextView. If you want to implement text wrapping by yourself, you can override TextView and use Paint's [`breakText(String text, boolean measureForwards, float maxWidth, float[] measuredWidth)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#breakText(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20float,%20float[])) function. Note that you have to specify text size, typeface etc to [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) instance.

Answer (score 4):

Add an invisible zero-width space ('\u200b') after each character:

```
textView.setText(longlongText.replaceAll(".(?!$)", "$0\u200b"));
```

This works also for long strings containing no spaces (for example, link addresses). Standard TextView tries to break a link by question mark '?' and slash '/'.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CharacterWrapTextView extends TextView {
  public CharacterWrapTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public CharacterWrapTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CharacterWrapTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @Override public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText(text.toString().replace(" ", "\u00A0"), type);
  }
}
```

---

```
<com.my.CharacterWrapTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"/>
```

---

[image]

(yellow background: normal textview)

Answer (score 1):

The following extension method implements @atarasenko's solution in C# which may be useful for people working with Xamarin.Android. The resultant string will wrap within a TextView character-by-character.

```
/// <summary>
/// Add zero-width spaces after each character. This is useful when breaking text by
/// character rather than word within a TextView.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">String to add zero-width spaces to.</param>
/// <returns>A new string instance containing zero-width spaces.</returns>
public static string AddZeroWidthSpaces(this string value) => Regex.Replace(
    value
    , "."
    , "$0\u200b"
);
```

Comment: Thanks, works in Xamarin Android still, and better than the above solutions.