# Android TextView character wrap CJK

Tags: textview, cjk, word-wrap, android

Hi I am having trouble wrapping text in textview. I want the textView to to character wrap. 
I have this Japanese text "コーヒーイベントを行いますよ!!!11月23日19時より開催予定です。コーヒーイベントを行いますよ!"

The layout is like this

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewToUpdate"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

but when I set `textViewToUpdate` to the Japanese characters, the characters are displayed as

```
コーヒーイベントを行います <free space - here>
よ!!!11月23日19時より開催予定です。コーヒーイベントを行いますよ!
```

I want it to display like below, how do you do it?

I dont know what is wrong with the TextView. In iOS there is the option "character wrap". 
In Android it is not available.

```
コーヒーイベントを行いますよ!!!11月23日19時より開催予定です。コーヒ
ーイベントを行いますよ!
```

Update: when I tried the same text inside a WebView I was able to fix it with the css property

```
<span style='word-break:break-all;'>--japanese text here-- </span>
```

so it displays as I expected.
How do you apply the same concept on textView?
I have tried :

```
textViewToUpdate.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><u><span style='word-break:break-all;'>"+japaneseStr+"</span></u></body></html>"));
```

but no luck. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I had the same problem, found my answer here :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5491268/3519951